# ERROR : Cannot assign value of type '[Item]' to type '[String]'

Tags: ios, swift

I have added a search bar to my tableviewCell which has JSON data I have added a function which will be triggered when there is change of the text in the searchBar but I am getting an error.

This is my Item class:-

```
struct Item : Codable {

    var name = String()
    var symbol = String()
    var checked : Bool = false

    init(bitJSON: JSON) {
        self.name = bitJSON["name"].stringValue
        self.symbol = bitJSON["symbol"].stringValue
    }

}
```

This is my tableview class:-

```
var items = [Item]()

let searchBar = UISearchBar()
var filteredArray = [String]()
var shouldShowSearchResults = false


func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        filteredArray = items.filter({ (names) -> Bool in      // ERROR
            return names.name.lowercased().range(of: searchText.lowercased()) != nil
        })

        if searchText != "" {

            shouldShowSearchResults = true
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }else {

            shouldShowSearchResults = false
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }
```

Comment: If you only `filter` you will still get an `[Item]` out of it, you probably have to put a `map` in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`filter` does not actually change the type of array. `[Item]` after filtering is still a `[Item]`. Therefore, you cannot assign it to a property of type `[String]`.

To transform each element of an array to something else (`String` in this case), you should call `map`:

```
filteredArray = items.filter({ (names) -> Bool in
        return names.name.lowercased().range(of: searchText.lowercased()) != nil
    })
    .map { $0.name } // this line!
```

Comment: thanks the error has been removed but when I type in the search field, it does not show the results

Comment: @AkshayJain That probably is because of how you implemented the data source methods. They should use `items` as the source if `shouldShowSearchResults` is false, and use `filteredArray` otherwise. Check if you implemented the methods like I said.

Comment: you mean to say that I should try adding if else statements where there is 'items' involved?

Answer (score 0):

Filter simply generates a new array with certain elements from the oroginal array removed. If you wanted to generate a new array *from* that filtered array, you'd then do a map. Or, if you'd like to do it all in one step, you can do a flatMap:

```
filteredArray = items.flatMap { (names) -> String? in
    if names.name.lowercased().range(of:searchText.lowercased()) != nil {
       return names.name
    }
    else {
       return nil
    }
}
```

This will give you an array of all strings that meet your requirements.

Notes: In Swift 4.1, `flatMap` has been renamed to `compactMap`.

Comment: thanks the error has been removed but when I type in the search field, it does not show the results

Comment: Can you put in a breakpoint and see if there are any items in the array? Perhaps put breakpoints on the two return lines in the flatMap method and see if your filtering logic is giving you the results you want.

Comment: If `filteredArray` is the backing array for your results tableView, can you put a breakpoint in `numberOfRowsInSection` to check the count?

Comment: items.count is 100, filteredArray is the array of search results

Comment: Is `items` the backing array for the tableView or is `filteredArray`. If it's 'items' then of course the flatMap isn't changing anything. I guess I don't have enough details here.